# How to declare an empty rowset properly with SOCI?

Tags: c++, soci

Imagine that I have the following function. In case of invalid parameters or exception, the function has to exit with an empty `rowset`.

```
rowset<row> SelectAllFromTable(string tableName)
{
    session sql(odbc, "...");

    // if parameters are not valid -> return empty rowset<row>
    if (tableName == "")
    {
        // query that returns 0 result
        rowset<row> res = (sql.prepare << "SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE ID = -9999");
        return res;
    }

    string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

    try
    {
        rowset<row> rs = sql.prepare << query;
        return rs;
    }
    catch (exception const &e)
    {
        cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        // query that returns 0 result
        rowset<row> res = (sql.prepare << "SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE ID = -9999");
        return res;
    }

    // query that returns 0 result
    rowset<row> res = (sql.prepare << "SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE ID = -9999");
    return res;
}
```

The solution I wrote above works but my question is : **Is there a better way to return an empty rowset with SOCI ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the documentation hasn't much to offer to this I looked into the rowset Header: There is no default constructor for it and no public method to set the iterators, ergo you can't get an empty rowset by yourself.

Despite why don't you use exceptions which are just perfect for that case. Just don't catch the soci_error exception, then the caller `SelectAllFromTable` could catch it. This would have many advantages:

- The caller would know if there is really no data in the table or there is no table
- The caller could know why he can't use the table (misspelled or security reasons)
- The caller could know if there are other troubles and take action or if not, rethrow it, so his caller might can.

Comment: Sorry for the late validation, it looks like the best solution in this case and I implemented it a few minutes ago. Thank you :)